# MYSQLI mysqli_real_escape_string and PHP problems

Tags: php, mysqli

Hey What's up Everybody… I am having a lot of trouble with this script.  I guess it is standard PHP MYSQLI stuff.  It was working until I tried to add the mysqli_real_escape string parts.  Any ideas?

```
<?php

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $address = ($_POST['address']);
    $city = ($_POST['city']);
    $state = ($_POST['state']);
    $zip = ($_POST['zip']);
    $persons = ($_POST['persons']);
    $damages = ($_POST['damages']);
    $complaint = ($_POST['complaint']);

    $safename = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $name);
    $safeaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $address);
    $safecity = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $city);
    $safestate = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $state);
    $safezip = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $zip);
    $safedate = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $date);
    $safepersons = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $persons);
    $safedamages = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $damages);
    $safecomplaint = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $complaint);

    $query = "INSERT INTO blacklisted 
    (
    name, 
    address, 
    city, 
    state, 
    zip, 
    date, 
    persons, 
    damages, 
    complaint
    )
    VALUES 
    (
    ".$safename.", 
    ".$safeaddress.", 
    ".$safecity.",
    ".$safestate.", 
    ".$safezip.", 
    ".$safedate.", 
    ".$safepersons.", 
    ".$safedamage.", 
    ".$safecomplaint."

    )";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    mysqli_free_result($result);

    mysqli_close($connection);

    ?>
```

I was under the impression everything would be fine but I am now confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String values in SQL queries must be quoted. You are just escaping the data and them dumping it into the string. (I don't understand why you are concatenating all your strings instead of using variable interpolation there either).

You shouldn't be mashing user input into strings of SQL anyway. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: do you mean '.$name.' ?

Comment: so no problems with the mysqli_real_escape_string part?

Comment: @Julian he means it would work with `'".$safepersons."'`. Double quotes for PHP, single quotes for MySQL. But don't do it. It's a bad idea for several reasons. Read up on prepared statements, like Quentin said. They're easier, safer, and make for nicer and more maintainable code

Comment: The mysqli_real_escape_string part should be removed when you switch to using prepared statements.

Comment: ' " .$safepersons. " ' did the trick!  Can anyone post an example of what this would look like with prepared statements?

Comment: also what is variable interpolation?

Comment: This page is recording data from a bunch of forms, so therefore the $_POST variables...

Comment: It should be noted that if you don't have mysqlnd installed/loaded you will get an undefined reference when trying to call "mysqli_stmt_get_result()".

I though someone should also note this before using prepared statements.